# Remove double backslash from c# json reponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to generate string like given below

```
"\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x"
```

but I am not able to give it as similar in code because '\' is escape sequence so i have tried both

```
"\\x{data,BARCODE,004}\\x"
```

and

```
@"\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x"
```

but in json response (in Postman and Java client application) getting as this

```
"\\x{data,BARCODE,004}\\x"
```

is anyway to remove \ or to get response as this

```
"\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x"
```

Comment: when you say you are getting the response as \\x... where are you seeing it? is it somewhere that shows you escaped data? which would show single \ as \\

Comment: When i use postman client i am getting like this

Comment: and even in java client application also getting same response like this

Comment: Whenever you serialize a string to JSON there were some characters replaced or escaped. And the backslash is one of thoese "will be escaped" chars, because it is the escape char for JSON => https://json.org - "my \ string" = json serialize => "my \\ string" = json deserialize => "my \ string"

Comment: see a [.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mttqmA)

Comment: let me try this hold on

Comment: As you suggested it is working because the text in print or display time it will reduce special escape character. My problem with postman response still it is not not working

Comment: If you want to have a JSON response of *"\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x"* then sorry there is no way, because that is an invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your given string is an invalid JSON string and thous can't be serialized as valid JSON without escaping the backslash. But if your receiving side needs to get this kind of result it simply doesn't support JSON and you have to provide the given format.

In ASP.Net your controller has to return a `ContentResult` as `IActionResult`. In that case the content will be given as is without any serialization:

```
public IActionResult MyControllerMethod(SomeRequest request)
{
    // Call your business model to receive the desired string...
    var content = @"\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x";

    return Content(content);

    // Or for full control
    // return new ContentResult { Content = content, ContentType = "text/glibberish", StatusCode = 418 };
}
```

Just tested the code with swagger/swashbuckle and everything seems to be fine:
[image: Swagger test request]

Also tested it with Postman:
[image: Postman test request]

And with powershell:
[image: Powershell test request]

Comment: string generation content is failed  - var content = "\x{data,BARCODE,004}\x"

Comment: Sorry, cause the text is hardcoded in this example, it has to be escaped for the compiler. Fixed it by marking the text with the `@` sign. Now it compiles.

Comment: sorry i tried this getting "\\x{data,BARCODE,004}\\x", is any other way is possible

Comment: This was a joke, you should take `text/plain`.

Comment: same result in postman coming with double backslash "\\x{data,BARCODE,004}\\x"

Comment: I just tested the call from Postman and Powershell also and everything seems to be fine (see my updated answer). Maybe there is something wrong in how you call your method, cause I'm not able to reproduce your behaviour on my site. So maybe try to re-create an empty project and start off with the given example and check if it produces the desired output. If yes evolve it to your solution and check where the error happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206776/discussion-between-saneesh-kunjunni-and-oliver).